# Why is it that when I have X(long) / (Y*Y*Y)(long) I get Error: Divide by Zero?

Tags: java, math, divide-by-zero

In my example X is already long and Y is a long also. I am not casting at then.

I really just want to divide by a number that is cubed. (using native libraries)

These numbers are extremely large. If I convert them to floats and do it, its value is Infinite...

```
System.out.println(formatter.format("%20d", (X/(Y*Y*Y))));
```

Y is an extremely large number, it is not 0. X is a measurement of time in milliseconds.

I will post the exact code in a short while if this question doesn't get closed... I don't have access to it right this minute.

**Context:** I am dealing with a big notation calculation for O(n^3).

**Error:** "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero"

**Answers:**

> Assuming you didn't really mean the quotes, the likely reason is that
>   Y * Y * Y is greater than 2 ^ 31. It's overflowing, with a lower part
>   of 0. I believe this would only happen if Y is a multiple of 2^11
>   (2048) - but I'm not certain*

***-This is the case for me, Y is a multiple of 2048, hopefully this helps with trying to find a solution.***

```
    // Algorithm 3
    for( int n = 524288; n <= 5000000; n *= 2 ){
        int alg = 3;
        long timing;
        maxSum = maxSubSum3( a );
        timing = getTimingInfo( n, alg );
        System.out.println(fmt.format("%20s %20d %20d %20d %20d %20s%n", "Alg. 3", n, timing, timing, timing/(n*n), "time/(n*log(n))"));
    }
```

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: Presumably because `Y` is zero? if that's the case, then no amount of multiplying it by itself will change that fact.

Comment: Read the api docs for BigDecimal.

Comment: @KRB, the code you posted probably does not compile (note that you used a string literal: `"(X/(Y*Y*Y))"`, not a number). What people ask from you when they ask for code, is you post just enough code that people can run on their own PC that exactly shows the problem you're experiencing. Could you post such a snippet please?

Comment: Probably a red herring, but I have to ask:  Are you actually getting an error such as "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero", or are you getting 0 *as an answer*?  If Y*Y*Y > X, then 0 would be the expected answer, since this is integer division.

Comment: @GreenMatt I am getting the exact error you stated. Execption by zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you didn't really mean the quotes, the likely reason is that Y * Y * Y is greater than 2 ^ 31.  It's overflowing, with a lower part of 0.

I believe this would only happen if Y is a multiple of 2^11 (2048) - but I'm not certain.

It can be avoided by making sure that the computation of Y^3 is done using some datatype that can hold it.  If it's less than 2 million, you can use a long instead.  If not, you'll have to either use a double or a BigInteger.  Given that your other value is in milliseconds, I'd guess that floating point would be fine.    So you'd end up with:

```
System.out.println(formatter.format("%20d", (int)(X/((double)Y*Y*Y))));
```

You may want to use floating point for the output as well - I assumed not.

Comment: Y IS a multiple of 2048. I am multiplying Y by 2 through each iteration of a loop and it starts at 2048. I think you are on to something. How do I solve this.. lol I need it to be these numbers.

Comment: @KRB:  Are you sure your Y is a multiple of 2048?  I ask because the closest multiple of 2048 to 137600000 is 134217728.  However, I have doubts that this is the problem - MAX_VALUE for long is 2^63-1, so I cubed 2097152 (=2^21) which caused a rollover, but not a divide by 0 error (although this might be JVM dependent).  However, using a millisecond representation of the current time and dividing by 137600000^3 gives 0; thus I wonder if you're using this result as the divisor in another calculation which is really giving your error.

Comment: I don't use the result of this calculation it is only printed. @GreenMatt

Comment: I didn't see "If I convert them to floats and do it, its value is Infinite..." before - sorry.  Given that, I have to conclude that either Y is 0, or you used the format shown - %d - which would be invalid.  You need to break this up into multiple lines of code, and put in prints, asserts, or some other debugging mechanism so that you can see where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Surely you don't mean to pass "(X/(Y*Y*Y))" as a string literal? that's a string containing your express, and not compilable Java code that expresses a computation that Java will perform. So that's problem #1: remove those quotes.

Second, the formatter has nothing to do with dividing numbers, so that is not relevant nor your problem.

Third, casting has nothing to do with this. Your problem is exactly what it says: you're dividing by zero. I assume you don't want to do that. So, Y must be 0.

Fourth, nothing here uses native libraries. It's all Java. Right, that's what you mean?

You may want to use BigInteger to perform math on very large values that overflow a long. But, that will not make division by zero somehow not be division by zero.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try, either with `long` or `float` conversions:

```
( ( X / Y ) / Y ) / Y
```

If `Y` is a high enough power of 2 (`2^22` or more), then `Y^3` will be a higher than `2^64` power of 2. And `long` uses 64 bits in Java, isn't that correct?